# JPA: in parent child relation -> parent is not updated

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, h2

When developing my application, I used to receive a NullPointerException when working with a value from my database. This value was set in a parent child relationship. After a bit of debugging I saw, that this value has never been updated by the database.
The code looks like this: I have two entities, the parent is created first and somewhat later the child is created, too. And after this creation, the parent is updated. And this update was never performed by the underlying database.
The code for the creation is this:

```
    ...
    EntityManager em = Activator.getEntityManager();

    Customer c = Customerem.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Customer c WHERE c.name=:arg")
        .setParameter("arg", "abc").getSingleResult();

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    CustomerRelation cr = new CustomerRelation();
    cr.setCustomerId("123");
    cr.setAccessCode("456");
    cr.setCustomer(c);

    em.flush(); 

    c.addCustomerRelation(cr);
    em.persist(c);
    em.persist(cr);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

When looking into the log of the database, I can see an INSERT statement for CustomerRelation, but nothing concerning the customer... What do I miss here?

Btw, here are the entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Customer
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected int cId;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy="customer", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})  
    protected List<CustomerRelation> relations;

    ... other fields, Getter/Setter, etc.

    public void addCustomerRelation(CustomerRelation relation) 
    {
        if (relations == null)
        {
            relations = new ArrayList<CustomerRelation>();
        }
        if (!this.relations.contains(relation))
        {
            this.relations.add(relation);
        }
        relation.setPerson(this);
    }
}

@Entity
public class CustomerRelation 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected int rId;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Person.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="PERSON", referencedColumnName="pId")
    protected Person person;

    @Basic
    protected String customerId;

    @Basic
    protected String accessCode;

    ... other fields, Getter/Setter, etc.
}
```

As an additional information: I use Eclipselink and H2 as database...

Comment: Well, the test doesn't change any property of Customer that is mapped to the customer table. And you're using persist() to save an already persistent entity.

Comment: I create the CustomerRelation that is mapped to the customer. Yes, it is not changed, because it doesn't exist yet. And what should I use instead of persist?

Comment: **Customer** already exists. ou're not modifyin anything inside Customer, and you call persist() although it is already persistent. You just shouldn't call persist(c). And there is no point in calling anything else, since you haven't modified anything in Customer.

Comment: ok, I understand! But I think that I modify customer by calling c.addCustomerRelation(cr)...

Comment: This is just the inverse side of the ManyToOne CustomerRelation.customer. This association is stored in database by setting the value of a join column (foreign key) in the CustomerRelation table. Nothing in the customer table needs to be changed to add a relation to a customer.

Comment: ok, I see! In fact, there is no need to change the customer in order to add a relation to it. Isn't there any chance to store that relation in the customer table?

Comment: No. That's not how relational databases work.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why, but now I have a working solution. As I was really helpless all day,I finally just commented out the annoations in the entity class:

```
...
//@OneToMany (mappedBy="customer", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})  
    protected List<CustomerRelation> relations;
....
```

After commenting that out, I just tried a last time and had a look in the log. And there, I found these lines:

> [EL Config]: metadata: 2018-01-29 21:29:52.207--The element [field
>   relations] is being defaulted to a one to many mapping.
>
> [EL Config]: metadata: 2018-01-29 21:29:52.207--The target entity
>   (reference) class for the one to many mapping element [field
>   relations] is being defaulted to: class
>   de.mho.finpim.persistence.model.CustomerRelation.

So I scrolled down a little further and found this:

> [EL Config]: metadata: 2018-01-29 21:29:52.214--The join table name
>   for the many to many mapping [field relations] is being defaulted to:
>   CUSTOMER_CUSTOMERRELATION.
>
> [EL Config]: metadata: 2018-01-29 21:29:52.214--The source primary key
>   column name for the many to many mapping [field relations] is being
>   defaulted to: CID.
>
> [EL Config]: metadata: 2018-01-29 21:29:52.214--The source foreign key
>   column name for the many to many mapping [relations] is being
>   defaulted to: Customer_PID.
>
> [EL Config]: metadata: 2018-01-29 21:29:52.214--The target primary key
>   column name for the many to many mapping [field relations] is being
>   defaulted to: RID.
>
> [EL Config]: metadata: 2018-01-29 21:29:52.214--The target foreign key
>   column name for the many to many mapping [relations] is being
>   defaulted to: relations_RID.

And here I got, what I expected to be there with the annotations in the entity class! I absolutely do not understand, why the join table is created after I removed the annotations, but in the end, it helps...